# $or aggregate in mongodb 3.4

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I am trying hard to familiarize my self with pymongo and mongodb
This query is very basic and very easy, but I am struggling to make it works

```
match = { "$match": {"$or" : [{"book.author" : ".*"+name+".*"},
                      {"book.editor" : ".*"+name+".*"},
                     {"book.illustrator" : ".*"+name+".*"}]}}
count = {"$count": "tot"}
cur = db.collection.aggregate([match, count])
```

I am using mongodb 3.4 which provides all of that pipeline stages. 
I don't know why it return null while the data is exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression syntax is wrong. If you want to do a wildcard search you will need to use a [regular expression operator $regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/query/regex/) like so (the `$options: 'i'` part is to make the search case-insensitive):

```
match = { "$match": {"$or" : [{"book.author" : {"$regex": name, "$options": "i"}},
                      {"book.editor" : {"$regex": name, "$options": "i"}},
                     {"book.illustrator" : {"$regex": name, "$options": "i"}}]}}
count = {"$count": "tot"}
cur = db.collection.aggregate([match, count])
```

Comment: Thank you @dnickless . Is this code correct in python? I am a beginner in python. Many times I wrongly use (" "), because I read mongodb tutorials and work in python

Comment: I don't have a Python environment up an running so I don't really know. Are you getting errors? Which? Where?

Comment: Thank you @dnickless I found my mistakes. Thank you for helping me again

Comment: And I think I forgot some quotes. So check the updated answer.